# One scene - Lithuanian guy, window cleaner remotely deleting files on computer

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

This is a hard one, all I remember is one specific scene, even that one is unclear - a high building, there is a guy on window cleaner lift-platform outside, and two guys inside an office talking about blackmail or something, and there are some files on computer's hard drive.

Then one of them says something like this: "You see that window washer behind me? It's a Lithuanian spy and right now with that 'washing device' he is remotely deleting all files on your hard drive."

Not sure if it was a TV episode or a movie, I saw it on TV, maybe 5 years back.

Additional details: 
Not a Lithuanian movie, language was English, not an animated movie, and no idea how old.

Comment: I'm not sure but the scene somehow reminds me of a french comedy movie Micmacs (2009) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micmacs_%28film%29
There's a scene similar to your description where the guy washes the window from the outside and tries to listen to the conversation between two guys who are inside the building.

Comment: That won't be the one, actors and movie trailer doesn't ring any bells. Besides, Language was English, that i am 100% sure. But thanks for response, i appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know but that reminds me of shows like "Leverage" and "Hustle". so take a look at those imdb pages may be you'll recognize some actor http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1103987/ http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379632/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_13

Comment: @Lettmannen out of curosity, if you don't remember any thing about it. Any particular reason why you want to search for that movie or tv series

Comment: madmada, I haven't seen those series, not yet. But i would like to know more. Thanks. :) Panther, the same here. "out of curiosity". @Meat Trademark You could be on to something, I will check it out.

Comment: @Lettmannen I prematurely deleted my comments (to trim the thread) rendering your responses a schizophrenic babble. Apologies. Watch Close Encounters. Seriously. Do it. And then have some mashed potatoes and try to act like nothing is wrong. All Hail the Zoltán Kodály hand dance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be from the Showtime series [WEEDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeds_%28TV_series%29), season three, episode five. "Bill Sussman," aka Mr. Botwin, is in Mr. Wilson's office and is told, in no uncertain terms, that they are surrounded by employees of the Government:

> SUIT: You see that window washer outside, cleaning the windows, Mr. Botwin? Notice anything unusual?
>
> BOTWIN: I don't know, should I?
>
> WILSON: He's a white guy?
>
> SUIT: Actually, he's a Lithuanian. And that squeegee he's holding is a remote, currently erasing your hard drive, Mr. Wilson. Would you confirm that for me?
>
> WILSON: (looks at his screen and sees it go wavy then dark) Whoa.
>
> SUIT: That's because that window washer is not a window washer. He works for us. And that janitor in the hallway, he works for us too. Turn on your vacuum, Ivan.
>
> (Vacuum turns on)
>
> SUIT: Turn it off.
>
> (Vacuum goes off)

One more dark and great scene in a ground-breaking dark-comedy series. It was more than a little bit unnerving. No wonder the scene stuck out and was memorable. (To say more is not only a spoiler, but too hard to explain in a succinct fashion.)

No source I'm quoting from, I just played the scene a few times and transcribed it, best and fastest I could.